# error_cb in confluent-kafka-python producers and consumers

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm wondering what is the proper reaction to evens that lead to the error_cb callback being called.

Initially our code was always throwing an Exception from the error_cb regardless of anything. We're running our stuff in Kubernetes, so restarting a consumer/producer is (technically) not a big deal. But the number of restart were quite significant, so we added a couple of exceptions, which we just log without quitting:

- KafkaError._MSG_TIMED_OUT (both consumer and producer)
- KafkaError._TRANSPORT (consumer)

These are the ones that we see a lot, and confluent-kafka-python seems to be able to recover from them without any extra help.

Now I'm wondering if we were right to throw *any* exceptions in error_cb to begin with. Should we start treating error_cb just as a logging function, and only react to exceptions thrown explicitly by poll and flush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

librdkafka will do its best to automatically recover from any errors it hits, so the `error_cb` is mostly informational and it is generally not advisable for the application to do anything drastic upon such an error.

- `_MSG_TIMED_OUT` and `_TIMED_OUT`- Kafka protocol requests timed out, typically due to network or broker issues. The requests will be retried according to the retry configuration, or the corresponding API / functionality willl propagate a more detailed error (e.g., failure to commit offsets). This error can safely be ignored.
- `_TRANSPORT` - the broker connection went down or could not be established, again this is a temporary network or broker problem and may too be safely ignored.

Comment: I feel like I've seen these types of errors occasionally when trying to close the consumer, and then the application seems to hang. Is there a configuration option to forcibly return from the close after some amount of time? I have 'max.poll.interval.ms' set to max value for reasons, but that doesn't seem like it should have an effect on close().

Comment: `rd_kafka_consumer_close()` will block for up to max.poll.interval.ms waiting for final offsets to be committe. Also make sure to use the latest version of librdkafka since there have been some issues in earlier versions with close() taking too long.